# OpenCV continuously dropping frames

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, opencv3.0

I am trying to recognize the presence of a human in my video feed using `HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector()`.

For each received frame it checks if there is a human in it but for some reason OpenCV is dropping frames left and right to the point where my feed is so laggy. This [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fYZc.jpg) demonstrates the resulting feed delay and the dropped frames.

Below is the extracted code causing the issue

**EDIT**

*I tried resizing the image to 400X400 and it seems to be working better now. Frames are still being dropped once in a while but the feed is smooth this time around.* [New GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ7vm.jpg)

```
import cv2
import datetime

hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
hog.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())
hogParams = {'winStride': (8, 8), 'padding': (32, 32), 'scale': 1.05}

def detectHuman(frame):
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (400, 400))
    cv2.imshow('Reduced Frame', frame)
    result = hog.detectMultiScale(frame, **hogParams)
    print("Detection Took: {}s".format((datetime.datetime.now()-start).total_seconds()))
    print result

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    grabbed, frame = camera.read()

    if not grabbed:
        break

    detectHuman(frame)

    cv2.imshow('Main', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break    

camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: hog.detectMultiScale is expensive...

Comment: @Micka to this extent of lagginess? What would you recommend then? I have tried resizing the frame to 400x400 and it works just fine. Takes less than a second to run `hog.detectMultiScale`

Comment: processing speed depends on your hardware and image size. optimizations depend on your scenario. you could try to identify target regions from background subtraction, edge detection, skin color detection or similar and only evaluate resized target regions with hog. or try the gpu version ;)

Comment: @Micka thanks alot..Appreciate it